# Deezer album chart API returns different results with access token

Tags: deezer

I noticed that I get a different response to the Deezer API album chart request when a valid access token is included in the request. Without access token I get the full results, but with it, I only get the first 14 results. Also, those 14 results don't match the first results of the full results.

Request without access token (using [HTTPie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie)):

```
http 'https://api.deezer.com/chart/462/albums'
```

Response:

```
{
  ...
  "next": "https://api.deezer.com/chart/462/albums?index=10", 
  "total": 300
}
```

Request with access token (using [HTTPie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie)):

```
http 'https://api.deezer.com/chart/462/albums?access_token=frK...'
```

Response:

```
{
  ...
  "next": "https://api.deezer.com/chart/462/albums?access_token=frK...&index=10", 
  "total": 14
}
```

So are the album chart results filtered according to the requesting user? If so, how and why? Is there any way to get unfiltered results using the Deezer JavaScript SDK `DZ.api` call (that automatically adds the access token)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the token, as you should know, allows to identify the user. The rights (from the country, the label, the account...) according to the track are read in order to filter the availability of the tracks, that's why you can have different results with or without a token, even with 2 different tokens.

You can use DZ.api without login, so you will have only the results according to the current country. It adds automatically the token only if you're logged.

Comment: I understand country specific restrictions, but why do I see so few results when logged in (14) as opposed to when I'm logged out (300), if I'm in the same country? Why does something user specific affect what chart results are shown? Are they personalized by some metrics?

This is in the context of an InApp, so the user is always logged in.

Comment: As you said, they are personalized for the users, so without token, it is all the charts of the country.